# Where to place helper-functions, which need access to redux-state?

Tags: reactjs, redux

On the initialization of my React-app I fetch a list of settings from an API. The settings getting stored in the redux-state.

*They never will be changed by the React-app. The app just consumes the values. Should I place this values in the redux-state anyway?*

To use the settings in my components, I implemented several helper functions. For example widgetSettingsColor(key), widgetSettingsText(key), etc. which search for the given key and return the correct field or a default value.

How and where should I implement these helpers? Or should I move the whole Settings (data + helper-functions) to a Singleton-class and do not move the settings to the redux-state?

Comment: It’s just simple. No need for any helper functions. If you are using redux in your application just make an action call from a top parent component of the application which will fetch all settings and set them into redux state. You can access the settings from redux state wherever or whenever across application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define any helper method as you mentioned, into any JS file, and export them

```
src/helpers.js
```

```
import store from './Store';

export const widgetSettingsColor = (key) => {
  //Access redux store as below
  const someVar = store.getState().someParticularReducer.someParticularField;

  // return bla bla
}
```

From the above code, `Store` is the file where you defined your redux store, and by importing it, you can access the store manually and get any value from any reducer that you've configured

Comment: @RedBaron You foresee any problem with it? Redux is there to ensure unidirectional data flow, so seems fine to me

Comment: it seems like an anti pattern to me. I was just chasing a similar solution and went with middleware. I think it makes sense to catch actions there rather than rely on the store

Comment: This would be better as:

export const widgetSettingsColor = (state, key) => state.someParticularReducer.someParticularField;


This is now a selector, so you can use is like:

useAppSelector(state => widgetSettingsColor(state, key))

Answer (score 1):

Yes keeping settings in redux state only. that's the best option available.

I keep helper functions in src/helpers. You can then import these function to individual file to use.

```
src/helpers
```

You can create simple functions for these helpers and the export them.

```
export const search= () => {}
```